# is there a compelling reason to use php's list() function?

Tags: php

Can anybody provide an example of when php's list() function is actually useful or preferable over some other method? I honestly can't think of a single reason I'd ever actually want/need to use it..

Comment: When a function returns an array of a known size and you need its elements separately - `list($foo, $bar, $baz) = func();`. This would help to avoid of creating a temporary variable

Comment: @zerkms  okay well, I can think of many use cases.. my query is "good" use cases.  As in, something I can use this for that I can't do more elegantly some other way.  E.g. in your example.. I can't think of a compelling reason to not assign the resul of `func()` to an associative array.. especially since 99% (100%?) of the time the values would be associated with each other anyways..

Answer (score 1):

Got a simple sql result row (numeric), containing, say, an ID and a name?
A simple solution to deal with it, can be:

```
list($id,$name)=$resultRow;
```

Edit; 
or here's another:  you want to know the current key/value pair of an array
list($key,$val)=each($arr);

this can even be put into a loop

```
while (list($key,$val)=each($arr))
```

altho you could say a foreach is exactly this; but if the 
$arr changes in the meantime, well then it's not.  It has its uses. :)

Comment: How about `$resultRow['id']`?

Comment: if the result is associative then you do have $resultRow['id'], if it's numeric (eg returned with MYSQL_NUM) then you don't

Comment: numeric based arrays is a really bad practice for DB results

Comment: "It has its uses" --- not for a real world though :-)

Comment: but I don't see how those examples would be better than just using the (associative) array in the first place. Or as you said, using a `foreach` in the first place. I can think of many ways to "use" `list()`; I just can't think of a way that's "better" than the alternatives.  Both of those examples look like unnecessary steps.

Answer (score 0):

It's a handy function when you know the right hand side is returning an indexed array of a certain size.

```
list($basename, $ext) = explode('.', 'filename.png');
```

Note that it can be used in PHP 5.5 with foreach:

```
$data = [
  ['a1', 'b1'],
  ['a2', 'b2'],
];

foreach ($data as list($a, $b))
{
  echo "$a $b\n";
}
```

But if you prefer more verbose code, then I doubt you'll think the above is "better" than the alternatives.

Comment: I would never use either of these demonstrations of `list()`.  In both cases, I would be using square braced array destructuring.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to unpacking array data into variables, there are no features which the "language construct" `list()` has, but square braced array destructuring doesn't.

So, no, there is no compelling reason to have `list()` anywhere in a project where square braced destructuring is available.

In fact, square braced array destructuring can enjoy the use of the spread operator which `list()` cannot.